# Can I import snapshot in docker?

Tags: node, snapshots

How import snapshot in node which running in docker container? For example snapshot from [https://tezosshots.com](https://tezosshots.com/).

I see only one variant, it's copy file from 7z archive in mounted volume directory. Isn't right?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy the archive, you can use a volume when running the container. Then you can use the *tezos-snapshot-import* command of the official image:

```
docker run --rm -v ${HOST_TZ_DATA_DIR}:/var/run/tezos/node -v ${HOST_TMP_DIR}:/tmp/fast_node tezos/tezos:mainnet tezos-snapshot-import /tmp/fast_node/${MAINNET_FILENAME}
```

Replace variables to your needs, we assume that the snapshot file was downloaded to the *${HOST_TMP_DIR}* with the *${MAINNET_FILENAME}*.